# Get only 10 digits mobile number in mongodb?

Tags: mongodb, nosql, aggregation-framework

I have a collection called **profile** as below.

```
{
name :"abc",
mobile : 9876543210
},
{
name :"def",
mobile : 98454
},
{
name :"ghi",
mobile : 1234567890
},
{
name :"mno",
mobile : 125456
}
```

Now , i want the output as

```
{
name :"abc",
mobile : 9876543210
},

{
name :"ghi",
mobile : 1234567890
}
```

I have tried like this but it works only for string field.

```
db.profile.find( { $where: "this.mobile.length = 10" } );
```

Any help?

Answer (score 1):

You can try below aggregations in mongodb **3.6** and above

You can check the length of the string using [**`$strLenCP`**](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/strLenCP/) aggregation and then filter the document where string length is equal to `**10**`

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  { "$match": {
    "$expr": {
      "$eq": [{ "$strLenCP": { "$toLower": "$mobile" }}, 11]
    }
  }}
])
```

or even with the find query

```
db.collection.find({
  "$expr": {
    "$eq": [{ "$strLenCP": { "$toLower": "$mobile" }}, 11]
  }
})
```

For mongodb versions prior to **3.6**

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  { "$addFields": {
    "mobileLength": {
      "$strLenCP": { "$toLower": "$mobile" }
    }
  }},
  { "$match": { "mobileLength": 11 }},
  { "$project": { "mobileLength": 0 }}
])
```

Comment: Will it work for all versions? Mine is 3.4.2. and i am getting unknown top level operator as error. I think $expr is only for versions 3.4.6 and above.

Comment: Error: error: {
 "ok" : 0,
 "errmsg" : "unknown top level operator: $expr",
 "code" : 2,
 "codeName" : "BadValue"
}

Comment: Updated the answer

Comment: Even this is returning ten digits number why so?
db.profile.aggregate([
  { "$addFields": {
      "mobileLength": {
        "$strLenCP": { "$toLower": "$mobile" }
      }
    }},
  { "$match": { "mobileLength": 5 }},
  { "$project": { "mobileLength": 1,"mobile":1 }}
])

Comment: That's what question is about. Isn't it?

Comment: Ya but in my above comment i have given in match condition the mobile length as 5 and hence it should return only 5 digit numbers right?

Comment: Yes it is returning having 5 digits number

Comment: For your above collection it works perfect. https://mongoplayground.net/p/a8kAuGvFDnX

Comment: Could you update your version. Because converting decimal numbers to string produces error.